# Unmet dependencies for libstdc++

Tags: apt, c++

When i type:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++
```

i got:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++-4.8-doc : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-doc but 4.4.7-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
                 Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.6-doc but 4.6.4-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
                 Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-doc but 4.7.3-12ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.6-dbg : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-dbg but 4.4.7-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.6-doc : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-doc but 4.4.7-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.7-dbg : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-dbg but 4.4.7-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
                  Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.6-dbg but 4.6.4-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.7-doc : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-doc but 4.4.7-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
                  Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.6-doc but 4.6.4-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.8-dbg : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-dbg but 4.4.7-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
                  Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.6-dbg but 4.6.4-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
                  Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-dbg but 4.7.3-12ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-armhf-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armhf-cross but 4.7.3-11ubuntu1cross1.85 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Ideas ?

Edit:

Same issues with:

```
sudo apt-get install clang++
```

Got:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 clang-3.3 : Breaks: clang-3.4 but 1:3.4-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
 clang-3.4 : Breaks: clang-3.3 but 1:3.3-16ubuntu1 is to be installed
 clang-3.5 : Breaks: clang but 1:3.4-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Breaks: clang-3.3 but 1:3.3-16ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Breaks: clang-3.4 but 1:3.4-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
 clang-format-3.3 : Breaks: clang-format-3.4 but 1:3.4-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
 clang-format-3.4 : Breaks: clang-format-3.3 but 1:3.3-16ubuntu1 is to be installed
 clang-format-3.5 : Breaks: clang-format-3.3 but 1:3.3-16ubuntu1 is to be installed
 python-clang-3.3 : Breaks: python-clang-3.4 but 1:3.4-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-clang-3.4 : Breaks: python-clang-3.3 but 1:3.3-16ubuntu1 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.5 but 1:3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 python-clang-3.5 : Breaks: python-clang-3.3 but 1:3.3-16ubuntu1 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.4 but 1:3.4-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Already see that post. I try everything but didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

`libstdc++` is not a binary package name. Since a package matching the name `libstdc++` isn't found, `apt-get` searches packages that match this regex, and therefore wants to install 4.4, 4.6, 4.7, and 4.8 and the associated `-doc` and `-dbg` files. The same thing applies for `clang++`

Instead, the packages you are probably looking for `libstdc++6` (for your first command) and `libc++1` (for your second command).

Comment: I got somes issues with clang++, that why i try to reinstall it. I execute "sudo apt-get install libc++1", that work but i still have the error for clang++. I always install clang++ with apt-get install clang++. Why is that not working today ?

The original issue was: fatal error: 'cstdlib' file not found.

Comment: `clang++`, as in compiling C++ files with `clang`?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Why ?

Comment: Just checking. The `clang++` command is in the `clang-3.4` (or any other version) package; it's not a separate package. The error you describe is an `#include` not being resolved (in this case `cstdlib`). In this case, the file is provided by `libstdc++-4.8-dev` (replace the 4.8 with the GCC version you have). Can you check if `g++` is installed (`apt-cache policy g++`)?

Comment: `apt-cache policy g++
g++:
  Installed: 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6
  Candidate: 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6
  Version table:
 *** 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
`

libstdc++-4.8-dev is already installed. 

I was thinking, reinstall clang++ and libstdc++ will reinstall the missings files/packages.

Comment: The `libstdc++-4.8-dev` has the necessary includes, so you could reinstall that with the `--reinstall` option. Can you edit your question and paste the output of `echo | clang++ -Wp,-v -x c++ - -fsyntax-only`? This will tell us what paths `clang++` is searching.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14796/discussion-between-sancho-and-saiarcot895).

Comment: Command say: ` /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.4/include
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
`